# RDLC report not displaying on test server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just deployed my website to a test server, but the reports are not displaying but are displaying on my development machine! this is the error message:

The report definition is not valid or supported by this version of Reporting Services. This could be the result of publishing a report definition of a later version of Reporting Services, or that the report definition contains XML that is not well-formed or the XML is not valid based on the Report Definition schema. Details: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Please does anyone know what might be the issue?

Comment: What SSRS version on your server and where you build your report?

Comment: i am using Microsoft reporting that comes with Visual studio 2012(.rdlc), the test server is using Visual 2010.

Comment: In Vs2010 reports use `http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition` XSD schema, but VS2012 reports use `http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition` XSD. So the problem may be due to differences in versions (the error message says about the same).

Comment: i just copied the project files without publishing it first, and it works, could it be the publishing is adding files to it?